# How one can notice when a famous formulas is extended?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, problem-solving

This integral: $\int\left( \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \right)\frac{1+x\tan(x)+ \tan(x)-x}{1 +x\tan(x)-\tan(x)+x}dx$ seems to be complicated, but it can be easily solved if one know the formula: $$\tan(a+b+c)= \frac{\tan(a)+ \tan(b)+ \tan(c ) - \tan(a) \tan(b)\tan(c)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)-\tan(a)\tan(c)-\tan(b)\tan(c)}$$. so $$\int\left( \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \right)\frac{1+x\tan(x)+ \tan(x)-x}{1 +x\tan(x)-\tan(x)+x}dx = \int\left( \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \right)\tan(x+\frac \pi 4 - \arctan(x))dx$$ and this is a straight forward $u$ sub. "There is no way anyone can see that if they didn't know this problem before" that was my reaction but one of my friends who is known for being smart solved this in less than a minute!

The question is How one can notice a generalisation of  famous formulas ? by generalisation I mean a formula known based on 2 variables extended to more variables  as in my  example  .there are ton of these question that uses some  generalisation  of famous formulas  like $(a+b+c)^n$ The question is how one should notice them ? Do people memorise extended formulas like $\sin(a+b+c) $? or do they have to be so smart to notice them ? Is there is a way one can notice these ?

Comment: Experience. Lots and lots of hard-earned experience is the only way you'll become familiar enough with these extensions (as you call them) that you recognise cases of them on sight and be able to apply them. Sure, there are savants out there that can read a definition once and be immediately able to recogise when they can be applied in any given context, but you shouldn't count on being able to replicate that. For the majority of us mortals, experience is the only way (which means **practise**. Can't emphasise that enough)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the example. At $\pi/4$, I think the big fraction is $(\pi-4)/\pi<0$ but the tangent with the arctan inside is $4/\pi>0$.

Comment: @MarkS. somehow I messed up the signs coping this integral, now fixed

Comment: In the particular case of the sum formula for tangent, once you know that $\tan(x+y) = (\tan x + \tan y) / (1 - \tan x \tan y)$ it's easy to generalize to $\tan(x+y+z)$ by applying the formula iteratively, writing $\tan( (x+y) + z)$ in terms of $\tan(x+y)$ and $\tan(z)$ and then expanding $\tan(x+y)$. And generally this will work whenever you have a formula for $f(x+y)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.